# Send an email to already existing lead in the campaign Marketo using restAPI

Tags: rest, marketo

I am sending transactional emails using marketo rest API which is working perfectly.
I have a scenario where I need to resend the email to the existing lead in Marketo.
I don't see any option of that in marketo rest API. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

make the same call again? Unless you need to change anything, if you make the exact same call, it will resend the email. Just make sure the Smart Campaign in Marketo is set to 'run every time' rather than 'run once' (for each lead).